# Android - Dagger inject Shared ViewModel to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-2

I need to bind two fragments with shared ViewModel.

Component:

```
void injectMovieFragment(MovieFragment movieFragment);
void injectMovieCollectionFragment(MovieCollectionFragment movieCollectionFragment);
```

SharedViewModelModule:

```
@Provides
MovieSharedViewModel provideMovieSharedViewModel(Fragment fragment) {

    return new ViewModelProvider(fragment.requireActivity()).get(MovieSharedViewModel.class);

}
```

This code cause MissingBinding error on Dagger (cannot get Fragment from MovieFragment/ MovieCollectionFragment).

SharedViewModelModule v2:

```
@Provides
MovieSharedViewModel provideMovieSharedViewModelToMovieFragment(MovieFragment fragment) {

    return new ViewModelProvider(fragment.requireActivity()).get(MovieSharedViewModel.class);

}

@Provides
MovieSharedViewModel provideMovieSharedViewModelToMovieCollectionFragment(MovieCollectionFragment fragment) {

    return new ViewModelProvider(fragment.requireActivity()).get(MovieSharedViewModel.class);

}
```

This code cause DuplicateBindings error on Dagger.

To get sharedViewModel without Dagger2 injection, I simply using:

```
sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MovieSharedViewModel.class);
```

inside onViewCreated of MovieFragment & MovieCollectionFragment classes, and this works well.
How to properly inject this shared ViewModel using Dagger 2?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could add how you are using injection in your fragment. From the error it seems like you are not injecting the created fragment into your dagger graph.

This is required as fragments are normally created by android and you need to provide the created instance to dagger.

The way I used to do it is like expose my `DaggerComponent` from my `CustomApplication` class(You can also expose the component through your activity).
Then in the fragment's `onAttach` function inject the created fragment like this.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        (context.applicationContext as CustomApplication).applicationComponent.injectMovieFragment(this)
}
```

This should fix the error. Please provide how you are using injection in fragments for more complete answers.